# Alternate approach to SUMMARIZE function in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

Stuck with a slow performing report, and I have a number of measures that are based on the below code only modifying the measure used in the CALCULATE call to get a different result. 
I am putting this out to the group to see if I can find a better solution and move away from the use of SUMMARIZE which based on everything I have read is a performance nightmare.

```
__% Priority Orders Rank = 
VAR MedianItems =
MEDIANX (
    SUMMARIZE ( 
        ALLSELECTED ( Sales ), Sales[bill_to_id], Sales[billto_customer_name] ),
            CALCULATE ( 
                [__% Priority Orders]
            )
    )
RETURN
IF ( [__% Priority Orders] > 0 && [__% Priority Orders] <= .5 * MedianItems, "A",
    IF ( [__% Priority Orders] > .5 * MedianItems && [__% Priority Orders] <= MedianItems, "B",
        IF ( [__% Priority Orders] > MedianItems && [__% Priority Orders] <= 1.5 * MedianItems, "C", "D"
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `[__% Priority Orders]` is evaluated 6 times in the `RESULT` clause . There would be the chance to improve performance by keeping the result of `[__% Priority Orders]` in another `VAR` and reuse it in `RETURN`.

If your model has Customer and Sales separated in different tables, or *normalized*, it could possibly get more optimization chance by turning the code something like below.

```
VAR MedianItems = CALCULATE(
    MEDIANX('Customer', CALCULATE([__% Priority Orders])),
    ALLSELECTED('Sales')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Kosuke Sakai. Is the below code what you had in mind. 

`__Avg Order Size $ Rank = 
VAR MedianItems =
MEDIANX ( 
    Sales,
    CALCULATE ( 
        [__Avg Order Size $],
        ALLSELECTED ( Sales )
    )
)
VAR AvgOrderSize = [__Avg Order Size $]
RETURN
IF ( AvgOrderSize > 1.5 * MedianItems, "A",
    IF ( AvgOrderSize > MedianItems && AvgOrderSize <= 1.5 * MedianItems, "B",
        IF ( AvgOrderSize > .5 * MedianItems && AvgOrderSize <= MedianItems, "C", "D"
        )
    )
)`

Comment: I wonder if `[__Avg Order Size $]` is the same thing as `[__% Priority Orders]` in the original post? Or is it another measure? Presuming it is the same, it is `MEDIANX ( 'Customer', ... )`. `MEDIANX ( 'Sales', ... )` will make incorrect output. This is because in many cases VertiPaq query plan looks to be more optimized for relationship based queries. However, not knowing the details, I cannot say for sure this applies to your model. I appreciate if you try it and give us a feedback.